# Magento Website Redirect to Downloader page

Tags: magento, redirect

I tried to log in to the admin page of my magento website.
But is shows the redirect loop error.
When I go the the index page it redirect to the downloader page.
[image]
Manually clear the var/cache var/session folders, but do not work.
Also tried change web/url/base_url from 1 to 0, not work.
It maybe missing the mage.php file, but no idea what's that file, and how to fix the issue.
Can anyone help me to figure it out?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might get a better response on the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) rather than here.

Comment: @ Robbie Averill Thanks !

Comment: Checked the integrity of your Magento installation? No files missing? For example some `.htaccess` files?